# RxJS: Splitting an array result from Observable.fromPromise

Tags: arrays, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm using RxJS here and I can't seem to get over this *seemingly* simple issue.

```
rx.Observable
    .from([1,2,3,54,3,22,323,23,11,2])
    .distinct()
    .subscribe(function next (x) {
        console.log('Next');
        console.log(x);
    }, function error (x) {
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(x);
    }, function completed () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
```

The above code spits out each array item in order as expected.

```
rx.Observable
    .fromPromise(getNumbers([1,2,3,54,3,22,323,23,11,2]))
    .distinct()
    .subscribe(function next (x) {
        console.log('Next');
        console.log(x);
    }, function error (x) {
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(x);
    }, function completed () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });

function getNumbers (nums) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        resolve(nums);
    });
}
```

Here though I only get the full array (i.e. `[ 1, 2, 3, 54, 3, 22, 323, 23, 11, 2 ]`). Shouldn't RxJS be breaking the result apart? I'd hope it at least had some logic for this.

Thank you

Comment: Alternatively I would absolutely be willing to perform some sort of transform that could mutate the stream *after* the promise is resolved.. e.g. receive the full array (1 item in the stream) and turn it into array.length items in the stream.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

No it will not break them apart implicitly. If you want to split them use `flatMap` which will flatten the array:

```
 rx.Observable
    .fromPromise(getNumbers([1,2,3,54,3,22,323,23,11,2]))
    .flatMap(function(x) { return x; })
    .distinct()
    .subscribe(function next (x) {
        console.log('Next');
        console.log(x);
    }, function error (x) {
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(x);
    }, function completed () {
        console.log('Completed');
    });
```

Comment: Lovely, I didn't know that `flatMap` would flatten an iterable.