# RxJS 1 array item into sequence of single items - operator

Tags: javascript, rxjs, observable

Given such observable

```
Rx.Observable.of([1,2,3,4,5])
```

which emits a *single item* (that is an array), **what is the operator** that will transform this observable to a one that emits 5 single items (or whatever the array consists of)?

The example is on `.of`, but it would be the same for fetching arrays via promises, there might be many other examples. Don't suggest to replace `of` with `from`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can't think of an existing operator to do that, but you can make one up :

```
arrayEmitting$.concatMap(arrayValues => Rx.Observable.merge(arrayValues.map(Rx.Observable.of)))
```

or the simpler

```
arrayEmitting$.concatMap(Rx.Observable.of)
```

or the shortest

```
arrayEmitting$.concatMap(x => x)
```

That is untested so let me know if that worked for you, and that uses Rxjs v4 API (specially the last one). This basically :

- process each incoming array of values as one unit (meaning that the next incoming array will not interlap with the previous one - that is why I use `concatMap`)
- the incoming array is transformed into an array of observables, which are merged : this ensures the emission of values separately and in sequence

Comment: hmm, that makes sense what you wrote :) but it's strange that there's no operator for this. If you had to fetch data via AJAX/promise and the data happens to be an array of items - and you want to emit each of these items separately - would you do above?

Comment: you can simplify by by directly applying `.of ` but I thought you said you did not want to do that, i.e.     `arrayEmitting$.concatMap(Rx.Observable.of)`

Comment: `.concatMap(x => x)` - that's the answer!

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the flatMap operator (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32241743/3338239):

```
Observable.of([1, 2, 3, 4])
  .flatMap(x => x)
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));
// output:
// 1
// 2
// 3
// 4
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `from` now to convert an array into a sequence.

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/from.html

`from([4,5,6])`

Answer (score 4):

`mergeAll`:

```
Observable.of([4, 5, 6])
  .mergeAll()
  .subscribe(console.log);
// output:
// 4
// 5
// 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Dont understand why `concatMap(x => x)` or `flatMap(x => x)` works, it doesnt change anything.
This should work (rxjs 6 or above):

```
of([4,5,6]).pipe(mergeMap(from))
```