# Angular make multiple http request but wait for each one to finish before making a new one

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http

In angular app I have an array of literal objects containing a url property.
I need to make a http request for each of these object, but one after another.

example:

```
let arr = [
    {url: 'http://example.com/url1'},
    {url: 'http://example.com/url2'},
    {url: 'http://example.com/url3'}
]
```

(that is an example, they may be more of objects, and I don't know how many)

Now, I want to make a request to first url and when we have a response from it (or error, doesn't matter) THEN I want to make a request to second etc. Any idea how to efficiently implement that?

I don't want to make these request at single time - each one should be made only after previous was successful or failure.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution would be to use **concatMap**, **toArray** and **switchMapTo**.

So first you have a list of urls:

```
let arr = [{url: 'http://example.com/url1'},{url: 'http://example.com/url2'}]
```

Then you transform them to an Observable:

```
of(arr)
.pipe(
   concatMap(r=> http.get(r.url)), //MAKE EACH REQUEST AND WAIT FOR COMPLETION
   toArray(), // COMBINE THEM TO ONE ARRAY
   switchMapTo(http.get("FINALURL") // MAKE REQUEST AFTER EVERY THING IS FINISHED
)).subscribe()
```

Comment: I think you should use `from` instead of `of` to transform array into sequence. Reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56364082/10684507).

Comment: Just `concatMap` would suffice, no need for `toArray` and `switchMapTo`

Comment: is the concatMap sequentiaal? As in wait for one to finish before it goes to next call?

Comment: Yes it is sequential. Use forkJoin and an array of observables it you want to wait for parallel results.

Answer (score 0):

We can use tricky method for this. You have to create method in the service like below.

```
// TestService.ts
callUrlAsync(url): any[] {
    return this._http.get<any>(url);
  }
```

In the component you have to call this method as follows.

```
//component.ts

let arr = [{url: 'http://example.com/url1'},{url: 'http://example.com/url2'}, 
{url:'http://example.com/url3'}]

public i = 0;

//trigger method
testMethod(){
this.callUrl(this.arr[0]);
}

callUrl(url){
this.testService.callUrlAsync(url)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data);
      if(this.arr.length > this.i){
      this.i++;
      this.callUrl(this.arr[this.i]);
}
  }
  }, error => {
    this.Error(error);
    if(this.arr.length > this.i){
    this.i++;
    this.callUrl(this.arr[this.i]);
}
  }
  );
}
```

Comment: Bro why to iterate like this when we are already having rxJs's so many methods, No doubt this solution works but still we have so many better approaches, isn't it?

Comment: yeah using Forkjoin we can do that smartly. But I gave small solution to it. This page describe how use forkjoin for handle multiple http requests. https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your observables with `flatMap`. Since you have a list of observables (or a list of urls that you want to transform into observables), you can do this with `reduce`.

Example:

```
// just some options to make a simple GET without parsing JSON
// and reading the response status
const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Accept': 'text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  }),
  responseType: 'text',
  observe: 'response'
}; 

const urls = [
  { url: 'www.google.com' },
  { url: 'www.stackoverflow.com' },
  { url: 'www.imgur.com' },
  { url: 'www.reddit.com' },
];

const reducer = (cur, acc) => acc.pipe(
  flatMap(r => cur)
);

const all$ = urls.map(({url}) => 
                    // create the get requests
                    http.get(url, httpOptions).pipe(
                      // do something with the result
                      tap(r => console.log(r.url + ': ' + r.status))
                 ))
                 .reverse()
                 .reduce(reducer);

all$.subscribe(x => {});
```

Answer (score -1):

User `forkJoin` 
[Fork Join](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html)

```
let arr = [{url: 'http://example.com/url1'},{url: 'http://example.com/url2'},{url: 

'http://example.com/url3'}]

forkJoin(arr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Use **concatAll()** method from rxJs which collect observables and subscribe to next when previous completes. (Or you can use **forkJoin** for multiple request at single time.)

**forkJoin** -  This will group all your request and execute one by one.
**forkJoin** waits for each http request to complete and group’s all the observables returned by each http call into a **single observable array** and finally return that observable array.

It accepts array as parameter. for example -

```
    let response1 = this.http.get(requestUrl1);
    let response2 = this.http.get(requestUrl2);
    let response3 = this.http.get(requestUrl3);
    return Observable.forkJoin([response1, response2, response3]);
```

For ref. - https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61

> This operator is best used when you have a group of observables and only care about the final emitted value of each.

In another way you can call each request in previous request's error or success block, which is lengthy process.

Comment: You start your answer with *Use forkJoin for multiple request at single time.* when the question is literally *make multiple http request but wait for each one to finish before making a new one* so your answer doesn't answer the question and is not helpful.

Comment: @sloth even I have mentioned about `concatAll()` (If you read my answer), which does the same what OP wants, right?

Comment: Maybe you should make it more clear, then? Or give an example? I didn't downvote BTW.

Answer (score -1):

Use `concatMap`, make sure to `catchError` because you don't want the entire chain to fail if one link produced an error.

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-lhfdzj?file=index.ts)

```js
let results$ = from(arr).pipe(
  concatMap(({ url }) =>
    requestData(url).pipe(catchError(err => of(`error from ${url}`)))
  )
);
```