# Split array into chunks/bulks and made operations with them one by one

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, optimization, rxjs

I'm a bit sorry about tags, probably I understood my problem not right and used them wrong but..

The problem I'm faced with my project is new for me and I never before experienced it. So in my case I have a huge dataset response from DB (Mongo, 100'000+ docs) and I needed to `http-request` every specific field from doc.

Example array from dataset will be like:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    http: http.request.me
},
{
    //each doc of 99k docs more
}
```

So guess you already understood that I cannot use default `for loop` because

1. if it `async` I'll be made a huge amount request to API and will
   be banned/restricted/whatever
2. if I made it `one-by-one` it will take me about 12-23H of
   waiting before my loop completes itself. (actually, this way is in
   use)

> This is what I'm trying to do right now

3. there is also another way and that's why I'm here. I could split my huge array in to chunks for example each 5/10/100..N and request them `one-by-one`

   ```
   │→await[request_map 0,1,2,3,4]→filled
   │→await[request_map 5..10]→filled
   │→await[request_map n..n+5]→filled
   ↓
   ```

According to the [Split array into chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks?noredirect=1&lq=1) I could easily do it. But then I should use 2 `for` cycles, first one will split default array and second `async-request` this new array (length 5/10/100...N)

But I have recently heard about reactive paradigm and `RxJS` that (probably) could solve this. Is this right? What operator should I use? What keyword should I use to find relative problems? (if I google **reactive programming** I'll receive a lot of useless result with react.js but not what I want)

So should I care about all this and just write an unoptimized code or there is an `npm-module` for that or another-better-pattern/solution?

> Probably I found and answer here
>   [RxJS 1 array item into sequence of single items - operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43283276/rxjs-1-array-item-into-sequence-of-single-items-operator?noredirect=1&lq=1) I'm checking it now, but I also appreciate any relevant contribution
>   to this question

---

> RxJS has truly been helpful in this case and worth looking. It's an
>   elegant solution for this kind of problems

Comment: Just to clarify, is the entire array of requests in-memory, or do you need to query a batch of 5 requests from your database each time?

Comment: Y, the entire array with necessary urls are in-memory and I just need to query a batch of 5(n) requests from it one-by-one. As far as I'm understanding it, RxJS is good. But I still don't understand how to use it with `http` (but it's very easy to divide array as I want it to)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make use of bufferCount and concatMap

```
range(0,100).pipe(
    // save each http call into array as observable but not executing them
    map(res=>http(...)),
    //5 at a time
    bufferCount(5),
    //execute calls concurrently and in a queue of 5 calls each time
    concatMap(res=>forkJoin(res))
).subscribe(console.log)
```

Comment: As for now I'm using a bit another code from tutorial and it's been non-trivial to understand how ```import``` works in Node/Common.JS, But I just checks this one, and right after ```bufferCount(5)``` I receive the exact thing that I want. Also I'd like to add https://rxmarbles.com to the list of things that helped me to understood this.

Comment: Glad it helps solving the problem

Answer (score 2):

There's actually an even easier way to do what you want with `mergeMap` operator and it's second optional argument which sets the number of concurrent inner Observables:

```
from([obj1, obj2, obj3, ...]).pipe(
  mergeMap(obj => /* make a request out of `obj` */, 5), // keep only 5 concurrent requests
).subscribe(result => ...)
```